# Invalid compose project using include key

Tags: docker, docker-compose, include

I’m trying to use [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/14-include/#project_directory) `include` option in the docker compose file.

The problem in the error, which says nothing about how to fix it.

```
# docker-compose.yml

version: "3.9"

# include networks settings
include:
 - path: "../networks/dc.networks.yaml"

services:
 # shared instance of redis
 redis:
  image: ${IMAGE_REGISTRY}/${IMAGE_REDIS}
  pull_policy: ${IMAGE_PULL_POLICY:-if_not_present}
  restart: always
  env_file:
   - "${ENV_FILE:-.env}"
  command:
    [
     "redis-server",
     "--appendonly",
     "yes",
     "--requirepass",
     "${REDIS_PASSWORD}",
    ]
  expose:
   - "6379"
  volumes:
   - .data/redis:/data
  environment:
   - TZ=${TIMEZONE}
  networks:
   - inside


# ../networks/dc.networks.yaml
version: "3.9"

networks:
 dmz:
  attachable: true

 inside:
  internal: true
```

Trying to `docker compose up -d` returns

```
service "redis" refers to undefined network inside: invalid compose project
```

I expect it should work, according to the docker docs

Comment: (Do you actually need multiple networks, or custom networks at all?  If you delete all of the `networks:` blocks then Compose will provide a network named `default` for you, and if you're only using that network, you won't need this included file.)

Comment: @DavidMaze I have several different cmpose files, which i want to connect to these networks, that’s why i came to that `include` option